# Cannot install pip install pyautogui, error code 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

`pip install <package>` command is working for me, I tried installing `selenium` package it is working in my setup but when I try to install `pyautogui`, it does not work. Screenshots below. What could be wrong here:

**WORKS**:
[image]

**DOES NOT WORK**, Error:

> ←[31mCommand "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\homepc\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-q631su\pyscreeze←[0m

[image]

Comment: Try: `pip install Pillow`

Comment: That worked. I take it that `Pillow` is a requirement here? If you could add explanation as answer - will mark it as the answer then.

Comment: there are some packages that requires before installing the Pyautogui, refer to below link and follow instruction for your OS: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error message is just as it reads. You need the `Pillow` port of the `PIL` library as a dependency:

```
pip install Pillow # a popular port of the Python Imaging Library, which is needed here
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by using the command `pip3 install pyautogui` from the console terminal window of the workstation. The cause of the error is that before doing that I was trying to use an SSH terminal window to install the software remotely. The SSH terminal window environment does not support a window system.