# pip3 install pyautogui fails with error code 1 Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, python-3.5, pyautogui

I tried installing the autogui python extension:

```
pip3 install pyautogui
```

And this installation attempt results in the following error message:

```
Collecting pyautogui
  Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.33.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/00/zcr6mkx90hg7kr4x_ks6nhhw0000gn/T/pip-build-edy15oyn/pyautogui/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        version=__import__('pyautogui').__version__,
      File "/private/var/folders/00/zcr6mkx90hg7kr4x_ks6nhhw0000gn/T/pip-build-edy15oyn/pyautogui/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
        from . import _pyautogui_osx as platformModule
      File "/private/var/folders/00/zcr6mkx90hg7kr4x_ks6nhhw0000gn/T/pip-build-edy15oyn/pyautogui/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 4, in <module>
        import Quartz
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Quartz/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        import objc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/objc/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
        _update()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/objc/__init__.py", line 15, in _update
        import objc._objc as _objc
    ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyObject_REPR
      Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-35m-darwin.so
      Expected in: flat namespace
     in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-35m-darwin.so

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/00/zcr6mkx90hg7kr4x_ks6nhhw0000gn/T/pip-build-edy15oyn/pyautogui
```

My Mac OS version is OS X El Capitan 10.11.3, my Python3 version is 3.5.1, and my pip3 version is pip 8.0.2.

There seems to be a similar question on Stackoverflow ([Cannot install pip install pyautogui, error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502965/cannot-install-pip-install-pyautogui-error-code-1)), but the fix does not apply to my problem; I have already installed "pillow". Also, I have read the documentation (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoGUI), and installed pyobjc-core as well as pyobjc. Setuptools are installed and up-to-date.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this error (and install pyautogui)? I think the error might originate, because [_PyObject_REPR is missing in Python 3.5.1](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/issues/137/symbol-not-found-_pyobject_repr-on-python).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [a workaround](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/issues/137/symbol-not-found-_pyobject_repr-on-python). This code by "Kentzo" fixed the issue for me:

```
pip3 install https://github.com/GreatFruitOmsk/pyobjc-core/releases/download/v3.0.5.dev0/pyobjc-core-3.0.5.tar.gz
```

Since the code is not written by me, please use this workaround at your own risk.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED

Run:

```
1. sudo pip3 install pil

2. sudo pip3 install Pillow

3. sudo pip3 install pyautogui
```

Bingo! installed without an error

Answer (score 2):

If you are like me and had no success installing pyautogui, here is what I did to fix the issue:

1. Install Xcode from the Mac App Store. This is a requirement for installing PyObjC. Details can be found [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html).
2. `sudo pip3 install pyobjc-core`
3. `sudo pip3 install pyobjc`
4. `sudo pip3 install Pillow`
5. `sudo pip3 install pyautogui`

Steps 2, 3, and 5 are detailed [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

Step 4 is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502965/cannot-install-pip-install-pyautogui-error-code-1), another Stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of steps which worked for me on macOS High Sierra(10.13.4) :

- Install Xcode from AppStore
- activate virtual environment (if needed)
- pip3 install pyobjc-core
- pip3 install pyobjc-framework-Quartz
- pip3 install image
- pip3 install pyautogui