# I have installed pillow using pip3 but pyautogui fails with error code 1

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Every forum I have looked at says that:

```
pip install pillow
```

remedies issues with installing pyautogui, however, I have installed pillow and I am still receiving:

```
python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

Any suggestions? I also tried installing PIL but that failed as well with the same error.

Comment: Did you run the command as an administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to upgrade your setuptools? What version of it you use? Try this:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

If you have not installed setuptools, use:

```
pip install setuptools
```

Comment: I upgraded setuptools and tried running as an admin but it still throws the same error. Strange because I have installed several other packages with no incident.

Answer (score 0):

To anybody else who has this problem with this - I have found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074294/pip3-install-pyautogui-fails-with-error-code-1-mac-os)

Use the workaround he provides for pyobjc-core

```
pip3 install https://github.com/GreatFruitOmsk/pyobjc-core/releases/download/v3.0.5.dev0/pyobjc-core-3.0.5.tar.gz
```

(as is said on the other page, I did not write this so use at own risk - but worked for me)

and then

```
pip install pyautogui
```

Thanks to Timo Krall and Kentzo.