# Installing PyAutoGUI Error in pip.exe install pyautogui

Tags: python, pip, pyautogui

I have been installing PyautoGui on my WIN10 PC. But I am getting the following error, i have been getting a lot of errors jut to get this far.

i have been reinstalling python so its destination folder is in  **C:\Python** instead of **C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32** mabye thats why ? How do i  fix this ?

> C:\Python\Scripts>pip.exe install pyautogui Collecting pyautogui
>   Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.33.zip Collecting pymsgbox (from pyautogui)
>   Using cached PyMsgBox-1.0.3.zip Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1 (from
>   pyautogui)   Using cached PyTweening-1.0.3.zip Collecting Pillow (from
>   pyautogui)   Using cached Pillow-3.3.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl Collecting
>   pyscreeze (from pyautogui)   Using cached PyScreeze-0.1.8.zip
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kxm3249e\pyscreeze\setup.py",
>   line 6, in 
>           version=**import**('pyscreeze').**version**,
>         File "c:\users\home\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kxm3249e\pyscreeze\pyscreeze__init__.py",
>   line 21, in 
>           from PIL import Image
>       ImportError: No module named 'PIL'
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kxm3249e\pyscreeze\

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error message as you did. This workaround worked for me. Try these steps in order...

1. Install PyScreeze 0.1.7.
2. Update PyScreeze to 0.1.8.
3. Install PyAutoGui.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same error (albeit on Ubuntu 14.04). The missing module PIL is named Pillow (As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34512881/4335271)). So what I tried was (same in MacOS I think):

```
sudo pip3 install pillow
```

That translated to Windows would be:

```
pip.exe install pillow
```

Hope this helps you further.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of letting **PyautoGUI** get all the packages for you.

Install all of them individually. Then, run the `pip install --upgrade _packageName_`

Then run `pip install pyautogui`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to report that this installation error has been fixed as of version 0.9.34. All you have to do is install or update PyAutoGUI from PyPI.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
pip uninstall pyautogui
```

then

```
pip install pyautogui
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that on windows it is not rightly configured on windows path and therefore it cant find the module, to fix this try:

Control Panel \ System and Security \ System

then click: Environment Variables, and double click on path and append the directory you want to use.

full explanation on: https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/

you can also try:

Cmd:

```
python -m pip install < module >


git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY
```

or

To append to PYTHONPATH:

IDE:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('< path >')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can disable your Windows protection until you have installed it.

```
!pip install pyautogui
```